# What is the number of cores in aws.data.highio.i3 elastic cloud instance given for a 14 day trial period?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I wanted to make some performance calculations hence i need to know the number of cores that this aws.data.highio.i3 instance deployed by elastic cloud on aws has, I know that it has 4 GB of ram so if anyone can help me with the number of cores that would be really very helpfull.

I am working on elasticsearch deployed on elastic cloud and my use case requires me to make approx 40 million writes in a day so if you can help me suggest what machines i must use that can work accordingly to my use case and are I/O optimized as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance used by Elastic Cloud for `aws.data.highio.i3` in the background is `i3.8xlarge`, see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-reference-hardware.html). That means it has 32 virtual CPUs or 16 cores, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage-optimized-instances.html).
**But** you down own the instance in Elastic Cloud, from [reference hardware](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-reference-hardware.html) page:

> Host machines are shared between deployments, but containerization and
>   guaranteed resource assignment for each deployment prevent a noisy
>   neighbor effect.

Each ES process runs on a large multi-tenant server with resources carved out using `cgroups`, and ES scales the thread pool sizing automatically. You can see the number of times that the CPU was throttled by the `cgroups` if you go to Stack Monitoring -> Advanced and down to graphs Cgroup CPU Performance and Cgroup CFS Stats.
[image]
That being said, if you need full CPU availability all the time, better go with AWS Elasticsearch service or host your own cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I would request you to answer one more query of mine related to ES. link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57704269/11432290